# Converting from UTM to LongLat using Proj4 in C++

Tags: python, c++, geospatial, proj

I've been going around this issue for days, but haven't been able to find an explanation to what I am doing wrong. I hope you can lend me a hand.

I have a set of UTM coordinates `(epsg:23030)` that I want to convert to LongLat Coordinates `(epsg:4326)` by using the proj4 library for C++ `(libproj-dev)`. My code is as follows:

```
#include "proj_api.h
#include <geos/geom/Coordinate.h>

geos::geom::Coordinate utm2longlat(double x, double y){ 

    // Initialize LONGLAT projection with epsg:4326
    if ( !( pj_longlat = pj_init_plus("+init=epsg:4326" ) ) ){
       qDebug() << "pj_init_plus error: longlat";
    }

    // Initialize UTM projection with epsg:23030
    if ( ! (pj_utm = pj_init_plus("+init=epsg:23030" ) ) ){
       qDebug() << "pj_init_plus error: utm";
    }

    // Transform UTM projection into LONGLAT projection
    int p = pj_transform( pj_utm, pj_longlat, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );

    // Check for errors
    qDebug() << "Error message" << pj_strerrno( p ) ;

    // Return values as coordinate
    return geos::geom::Coordinate(x, y)
}
```

My call to the function `utm2longlat`:

```
...
// UTM coordinates
double x =  585363.1;
double y =  4796767.1;
geos::geom::Coordinate coord = utm2longlat( x, y );

qDebug() << coord.x << coord.y;

/* Result is -0.0340087 0.756025    <-- WRONG */
```

In my example:

- I know that **UTM** coordinates `(585363.1 4796767.1)` refer to **LongLat** coordinates `(-1.94725  43.3189)`.
- However, when called, the function returns a set of wrong coordinates: `(-0.0340087 0.756025 )`.

I was wondering if I had any misconfiguration when initializing the projections, so I decided to test the Proj4 Python bindings `(pyproj)`, just to test whether I got the same wrong coordinates... and curiously, I got the good ones.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

// Initialize UTM projection
proj_utm = Proj(init='epsg:23030')
// Initialize LongLat projection 
proj_lonlat = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

x_utm, y_utm = 585363.1, 4796767.1

x_longlat, y_longlat = transform(proj_utm, proj_lonlat, x_utm, y_utm)

// Print results
print "original", x_utm, y_utm    
print "utm2lonlat", x_longlat, y_longlat  

/* Result is -1.94725 43.3189  <-- CORRECT */
```

From what I understand `pyproj` is a set of Cython bindings over the `Proj4` library, so I am using the same core in both programming languages.

Do you have any clue as to what could be wrong? Am I missing some type of conversion in the C++ function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result seems to be correct to me, but it's returned in radians instead of degrees. Convert the result to degrees and check again.

Comment: That was it, thank you very, very much!! I would up-vote your answer if I could, but I have not enough reputation yet. I suppose that the Python bindings do the conversion implicitly. Hope this can be of help to others.